# Ubuntu joining a active directory domain

Tags: 12.04, active-directory, domain-server, join

during the command

```
sudo domainjoin-cli join *domain* *user*
```

I get the error

[image]

removing the .local and just using the domainame I get this error

[image]

Pretty new with Ubuntu and don't know what to do.

just for clarifying, it is a windows active directory named jacob.local

Comment: Which release of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I use 12.04 LTS

Comment: Check that your local PC's date and time match the server - AD only lets you be a minute or two out before causing problems.

Comment: Try this for some verbose logging: `domainjoin-cli --loglevel verbose --log /tmp/domainjoin.log join <domain fqdn> <AD account>`

Comment: Another one: Windows is case-sensitive. If at any time you need to use somethhing from Windows make sure you type it as it is. So `LOCAL.DOMAIN` and not `local.domain`.

Comment: the same error with likewise as the above screenshots, Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try Likewise

> Likewise Open graphical desktop utility for joining hosts to Active
>   Directory domains.

To install Likewise, just click on the image below:

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/)</sup>

Comment: have used this guide http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/336477-how-to-join-a-ubuntu-machine-to-a-windows-domain
and cant get it working, asked my teacher aswell and hes no idea what 2 do